# Why isn't the noun plural in “there must be some mistake”?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, singular-vs-plural, determiners

I'm learning English dialogue according to EnglishPod. There is a sentence:

> But there must be some mistake; my reservation was for a standard room.

1. Why isn't the plural form of "mistake" here?
2. *my reservation was a standard room*.  Can I remove the for? What's wrong with saying that?

Comment: _There must be some mistake_ is a fixed phrase used to save face and avoid accusing one's addressee of making the mistake.

Comment: Also why do you assume that must be multiple mistakes to end up with a room mix-up?

Comment: @Jim I assume (not to suggest that you may not) that the OP understands some as a quantifier.

Comment: @JimReynolds -  Ahh.  You’re probably right. That never occured to me

Comment: @Yuj Welcome to ELU StackExchange. As you are an English learner, you may wish to ask your quesion on the English Language Learner's SE site. You should ask two separate questions. You should include information that explains why you have your questions. If you have not looked up *some* in a dictionary, you should first do so.

Comment: @Jim Doh! Things never go my way. I could have omitted that softening language and scored one as a pedant. :'(

Comment: I have answered because it is not reasonable to expect a non-native new contributor to undertake or expand on (“one or more”, for example) analysis of the substantial available dictionary discussion of *some*. The second part of the question could have been asked separately but is relatively trivial. Leave open.

Comment: _There must be **some (kind of)** mistake_... "some" here is synonym with "a certain"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*some* is a determiner that helps specify the following noun. Part of the discussion is found in:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/some)
>
> Strong form of *some*:
>
> The strong form of *some* is stressed. This form contrasts with others or all or enough:
>
> *Why do some people live longer than other people?* (some, not others)
>
> *Some boys went to the front of the stage to get a better view. The rest of us couldn’t see a thing.* (some, not all)
>
> *There were some cakes left but not enough for everyone.* (some, but not enough)
>
> We can use this strong form to refer to someone or something particular but unknown, **especially with singular countable nouns**:
>
> *There must be some way of opening this printer!*
>
> *Some idiot driver crashed into the back of me.*

Or, in your question, *… must be some mistake*.

Similarly, in mathematics we might say *There must be some solution to this problem*.

In this usage *some* is implying *at least one*, or *one or more*.

The second part of your question is more trivial:  a *reservation* is not a *room*. You should say *for* so as to express the purpose of the reservation.